# C++ - Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.In msvcrt!memcpy () (C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm getting back to c++ and I'm using code::blocks. Everything was going fine but out of nowhere I started to get this error

> '`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.In msvcrt!memcpy () (C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll)`'

The code compiles with no errors, but when I choose the option 1 "[1] - ... " it throws that error.

I googled a bit but I couldn't find anything related or that could help me fix this problem.

My code it's this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int SeeData();
    int ChangeData();
    string AddTodo();

    class Data {
     public:
      string name;
      string surname;
      string age;
      string salary;
      string todo[];
    };

    string dataArr[] = {"Bernardo", "Piedade", "19", "540.50"};
    string todoArr[] = {"Create new functions"};

    int sizeOfTodoArr = sizeof(todoArr) / sizeof(*todoArr);

    int main() {
      int _menuInput;
      while (_menuInput != 0) {
        cout << "[1] - See data\n[2] - Change data\n[3] - Add TODO\n[0] - "
                "Exit\n\n>>";
        cin >> _menuInput;

        if (_menuInput == 1) {
          SeeData();
        } else if (_menuInput == 2) {
          ChangeData();
        } else if (_menuInput == 3) {
          AddTodo();
        } else if (_menuInput == 0) {
          system("exit");
        } else {
          cout << "Option not available";
          system("cls");
        }
      }

      return 0;
    }

    int sizeOfData = sizeof(dataArr) / sizeof(*dataArr);

    int SeeData() {
      Data _myData;

      _myData.name = dataArr[0];
      _myData.surname = dataArr[1];
      _myData.age = dataArr[2];
      _myData.salary = dataArr[3];

      string person[sizeOfData];

      for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfTodoArr; i++) {
        _myData.todo[i] = todoArr[i];
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfData; i++) {
        person[i] = dataArr[i];
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfData; i++) {
        cout << "Name: " << person[0] << "\nSurname: " << person[1]
             << "\nAge: " << person[2] << "\nSalary: " << person[3] << "\n\n";
        cout << "Todo List: \n\t";

        for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfTodoArr; j++) {
          cout << "\n\t" << todoArr[j];
        }
      }
    }

    int ChangeData() {}

    string AddTodo() {}
```

Edit: As u/Uninitialized said, the error was happening because the array todo[] didn't had a starting size.

Comment: When you catch the crash in a debugger, when in *your* code does it happen? Walk up the function call-stack until you reach your code.

Comment: By the way, technically your program is not a valid C++ program, as you use [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (for example `person` in the `SeeData` function), and C++ doesn't have those. Either make the size variables `constexpr` (or at least `const`) or use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @BernardoPiedade This data member declaration  string todo[]; is invalid. C++ does not support flexible arrays.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I built and run the application again and after selecting the option 1 I got the " process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) "

Comment: And you really need to do some more research about [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as proper usage of it will solve your problem.

Comment: `0xC0000005` is the MS Windows kind to say segmentation fault (or access violation how it's called there).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you, I'll give it a closer look and hopefully i'll make this work

Comment: `string todo[];` is not standard C++. `string person[sizeOfData];` is not standard C++. You are using compiler extensions which don't do what you think they do.  They have a specific purpose, and they can be used correctly only in certain, very specific ways, and you're not using them this way, hence the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(0xC0000005) error code denotes a memory access violation. The error message says segmentation fault that arises from the memcpy() routine in the msvcrt.dll file, even though you haven't used the instruction explicitly. The todo[] member in class Data seems suspicious, since it has no fixed size allocated (don't understand how your compilation was successful, but you should probably initialize it to a known size and check)

Comment: That basically did it, I had to give an array size to the todo[]. 
Thanks!